# Why does my image have very small height in IE11?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with positioning an image in a table using html and css only.

**CSS**

```
#mytable {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 340px;
    font-family: Calibri;
}

#myText {
    width: 320px;
    height: 235px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

#myimage {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 180px;
}

#mycontainer {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

#secondContainer {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

#divTable {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(243, 242, 237);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <table width="100%" id="mytable">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td id="myText" valign="top">
                    <div style="overflow: hidden; max-height: 340px;">
                        <span id="textcontent">
                            <h4>My text content</h4>
                            <span style="float: right;">Sample</span>Text<br>Here
                        </span><br>
                    </div>
                </td>

                <td id="myimage">
                    <div id="mycontainer">

                        <div id="secondContainer">
                            <div id="divtable" tabindex="-1" class="ms-composite" dir="ltr">
                                <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" style="position:relative" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

this is the result in firefox for example :

[image]

the same code in IE:
[image]

I am thinking it has something to do with the position absolute.

please help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with `overflow:hidden;`, IE11 thinks that the image's height is overflowing so, he is hiding the image. 
Your solution is to either remove `height:100%` or `overflow:hidden`from **secondContainer** and it will work in bouth browsers.

```css
   #mytable {
        border-radius: 3px; height: 340px; font-family: Calibri;
    }
    #myText {
        width: 320px; height: 235px; padding-right: 14px; padding-left: 14px; background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    }
    #myimage {
        border-radius: 3px; height: 300px; position: relative; min-width: 180px;
    }
    #mycontainer {
        left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: absolute;
    }
    #secondContainer {
        left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;  position: absolute;
    }
    #divTable{
        left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 0; opacity: 1; background-color: rgb(243, 242, 237);
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
            <table width="100%" id="mytable">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td id="myText" valign="top" >
                        <div style="overflow: hidden; max-height: 340px;">
                            <span id="textcontent"><h4>My text content</h4>
                                <span style="float: right;">Sample</span>Text<br>Here</span><br>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td id="myimage">
                        <div id="mycontainer">

                            <div id="secondContainer" >
                                <div id="divtable" tabindex="-1" class="ms-composite" dir="ltr">
                                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" style="position:relative" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing overflow:hidden didn't solve this for me in IE 11. Thanks for your help

Comment: This should work. I just tested in IE11 and I am seeing the whole image.

Curious why you're using a table for the layout but also the absolute positioning? This won't work very well for responsive views.

Comment: It's not a production code I just want to understand why would it work for all browsers except IE 11.

Comment: Yes it was my bad thanks removing overflow:hidden did solve my problem. Would it cause any trouble for other browsers though ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It was only making that if the image was overflowing, then, it wouldn't be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `position:absolute` property from  #mycontainer.

And one more suggestion:Use have lot of unwanted css remove those css.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  #mytable {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 340px;
    font-family: Calibri;
  }
  
  #myText {
    width: 320px;
    height: 235px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
  }
  
  #myimage {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    min-width: 180px;
  }
  
  #mycontainer {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
  }  
  #secondContainer {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
  }
   #divTable {
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: rgb(243, 242, 237);
  }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="main">
    <table width="100%" id="mytable">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td id="myText" valign="top">
            <div style="overflow: hidden; max-height: 340px;">
              <span id="textcontent"><h4>My text content</h4>
                                <span style="float: right;">Sample</span>Text<br>Here</span><br>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td id="myimage">
            <div id="mycontainer">

              <div id="secondContainer">
                <div id="divtable" tabindex="-1" class="ms-composite" dir="ltr">
                  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" style="position:relative" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know that it's too much CSS but I rmoved a lot of things from my code to end up with this sample this is why there is too much CSS, I didn't want to remove in case it is related to my problem.

Comment: Removing position:absolute is indeed solving the problem somehow but the image isn't positionned correctly in other browsers without it this is why I need it.